# jQuery to get matching nodes in XML

Tags: jquery, xml

A little background: I was rendering some XML on the page using XSLT, but we decided to make it more interactive and so now I'm doing a jQuery.ajax call to return the XML, and I'm parsing it in JavaScript.

I've been able to extract particular nodes from it using code like

```
var qpPlanNode = $(xml).find('MyNode'); 
var qpPlanNum = $(qpPlanNode).children('PLANNUM').text();
```

And that gets the plan number into qpPlanNum.  But in that XML I have something like

```
<xml>
  <MyNode>
    <PLANNUM>123</PLANNUM>
    <SOURCE>
      <TYPE>PreTax</TYPE>
      <AMOUNT>1234</AMOUNT>
    </SOURCE>
    <SOURCE>
      <TYPE>AfterTax</TYPE>
      <AMOUNT>456</AMOUNT>
    </SOURCE>
    <SOURCE>
      <TYPE>PreTax</TYPE>
      <AMOUNT>234</AMOUNT>
    </SOURCE>
  </MyNode>
</xml>
```

I would like to extract all the SOURCE nodes that have a particular value for TYPE.  I can't find a simple jQuery selector that that will do that.  In XSLT, I was doing `<xsl:variable name="afterTaxSources" select="SOURCE[TYPE = 'AfterTax']"/>`.  What's the JQuery equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled on this one, which seems like it is working:

```
var pretaxSources = $(qpPlanNode).find('SOURCE:has(TYPE:contains("PreTax"))');
```

Does anybody see any reason why it wouldn't?

Even better, I can combine multiple types using

```
var pretaxSources = $(qpPlanNode).find('SOURCE:has(TYPE:contains("PreTax"),TYPE:contains("Employee"))');
```

Comment: it looks good to me, and if its working go for it. It seems concise enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
var xml = "<xml><MyNode><PLANNUM>123</PLANNUM>    <SOURCE>      <TYPE>PreTax</TYPE>          <AMOUNT>1234</AMOUNT>    </SOURCE>    <SOURCE>      <TYPE>AfterTax</TYPE>          <AMOUNT>456</AMOUNT>    </SOURCE>    <SOURCE>      <TYPE>PreTax</TYPE>          <AMOUNT>234</AMOUNT>    </SOURCE>  </MyNode></xml>"

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
$xml = $(xmlDoc)
$source = $xml.find('TYPE:contains("AfterTax")').parent();
console.log($source);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JdZzH/

**alternatively**
*however, i cannot get this to work properly in a live example*

```
  console.log($('TYPE:contains("AfterTax")').parent('source'));
```

should do it, however, I am having trouble getting a jsfiddle to work. it keeps seeing `<MyNode>` as the parent, however,

```
$('TYPE:contains("AfterTax")').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
```

works as expected, I would try this in something other than jsfiddle.

## Utilmately

I think [.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) are what you are looking for.