# Need to extract XML node using jquery, where node's sibling equals a certain value; using xPath now

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath

Here is a snippet of the XML file:

```
<Catalog>
  <CDs>
    <CD>
      <Manuals>
        <Manual>123DHX<Manual>
        <Manual>5axDHX<Manual>
        <Manual>5DaDHX<Manual>
        <Manual>5dADHX<Manual>
        <Manual>10XDHX<Manual>
      </Manuals>
      <SomeOtherNode>text</SomeOtherNode>
      <YetAnotherNode><text</YetAnotherNode>
      <Blueprint>No.8</Blueprint>
    </CD>
  </CDs>  
</Catalog>
```

Currently, **I'm using xPath to select the Manuals node, where the Blueprint node (it's sibling) equals the value in a select/dropdown box**.

```
xmlobject.selectSingleNode("/Catalog/CDs/CD/Manuals[../Blueprint='" + document.getElementById("Blueprint_Select").value + "']");
```

**How can I do the equivalent in jQuery?**

I tried the follwoing but it selects the Blueprint node, not its sibling, the Manuals node, which is what I want:

```
$(xmlobject).find("Blueprint:contains(" + $("#Blueprint_Select").val() + ")");
```

I found this link, [jQuery to get matching nodes in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500355/jquery-to-get-matching-nodes-in-xml), but it didn't help much, since .has() is for descendents, and I can't find an similar syntax in jquery for ascendents or siblings.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<Manuals>` element is always the immediate sibling of the `<Blueprint>` element, you can use the [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method:

```
$(xmlobject).find("Blueprint:contains(" + $("#Blueprint_Select").val() + ")")
            .prev("Manuals");
```

**EDIT:** If you cannot predict the order of the elements, use the [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$(xmlobject).find("Blueprint:contains(" + $("#Blueprint_Select").val() + ")")
            .siblings("Manuals");
```

Comment: Thank you.  That would make things much easier; however, I can't predict the order of the sibling tags in the XML file.  The hierarchy is consistent, but the order for siblings is not guaranteed.