# Javascript XML loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a problem with load XML data to javascript using jQuery.

I have a xml here:

```
<config>
<device>
    <node>1</node>
    <name>Block</name>
    <description>Block in saloon</description>
    <area>Salon</area>
</device>   
<device>
    <node>2</node>
    <name>Line</name>
    <description>Lottr</description>
    <area>Living room</area>
</device>   
</config>
```

I would like to find device name where node is = 2.

Here is the code I have:

```
       $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "config2.xml",
         dataType: "xml",
         success: function(xml) {
            var kurs = $(xml).find('name').text();
            alert(kurs);
         }
   });
```

What should I put in var kurs ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to put inside `kurs` and why?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the file being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "config2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      $(xml).find('device').each(function () {
        var node = $(this).find('node');

        if (node.text() == '2') {
          name = $(this).find('name').text();
        }

      });
    }
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVal;
$(xml).find('node').each(  //find the node and loop through them
    function(){
        var node = $(this);  
        if (node.text==="2") {   //see if the node's value is 2
            myVal = node.siblings("name").text();  //find the sibling name element
            return false;  //exit the each loop
        }
    }
);
console.log(myVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question: [jQuery to get matching nodes in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500355/jquery-to-get-matching-nodes-in-xml)

I think something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "config2.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
        //this should get you the device node 
        var $kurs = $(xml).find('node:contains("2")').parent();
        //this should get you the name from the device node
        var name = $kurs.find('name'); 
     }
});
```